# Источники данных для Visual Basic

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2019

как включить источники данных для Visual Basic?
Использую visul studio 2019.

Вот что пишет: "Это окно не поддерживается для выбранного проекта. Чтобы выполнить действия по включению привязки, перейдите по следующему адресу: aka.ms/WinForms/DataBinding". По ссылке информации не нашел.

Загрузил доп модули - ничего. А в си шарп источники по умолчанию доступны. Нужен бейсик
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: .NET 5? Введение новых возможностей в VB.NET сильно отстаёт от C#. А иногда они вообще не реализуются. Так что создавайте привязки вручную, благо это несложно. Как вариант, создайте привязки в проекте на FW 4.*, а потом скопируйте в новый. Ну или переходите на C#.

Comment: Проблема оказалась куда проще... Я просто выбрал не тот проект с VB(.NET) вместо .NET Framework